# Access Linux Samba share from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, samba

I have created a Samba share on Ubuntu 20.04 for a Linux directory and I have set the necessary port access in UFW namely 137/udp, 138/udp, 139/tcp, and 445/tcp. When I attempted to add a network location on Windows 10 with File Manager, at the end of the process it prompted me for a username and password. I had configured the share to not use a password so I believe that it wanted a password to connect to the Linux machine. I believe that I was confused as to what password I should enter and gave the wrong one. The net result is that I cannot connect from Windows 10 to this share and I can find no way to change the password. Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 2):

> I had configured the share to not use a password

Samba does not actually support per-share passwords. This security model *was* used in the Windows 98 era, but was completely removed from Samba in 2012. (Meanwhile Windows NT/2000/XP series never had per-share passwords in the first place, they were account-based the whole time.)

All SMB security is now **account-based** (just like in SSH and other protocols) – you provide a username and password to log in to the SMB server, and then access to shares is granted depending on your user account.

> so I believe that it wanted a password to connect to the Linux machine

That's almost right.

By default, Samba indeed uses the same system accounts as Linux itself does. The only difference is that the *passwords* are stored separately – Samba needs to store a NTLM-compatible password hash, as it cannot use the standard Linux hashed passwords.

This means that you must set a "Samba password" for your Linux user account before you can connect – use `smbpasswd` to do this on the Linux server:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a jonathan
```

(The Samba username always needs to match your Linux username in order for file permissions to work correctly, but the passwords can be different.)

> I have set the necessary port access in UFW namely 137/udp, 138/udp, 139/tcp, and 445/tcp.

SMB runs over 445/tcp alone. (Unless your client is running Windows 95/98, which needs 139/tcp.)

Port 137/udp is used for LAN hostname resolution (NBNS) and port 138/udp is used for nearby computer discovery ('Computer Browser' service) – both are completely optional for SMB, and in fact both are NetBIOS-based services which most Windows 10 clients have disabled along with disabling SMBv1.

Comment: My problem is that I entered bad credentials and can find no way to fix the problem.